# Nginx automatically adds wildcard to redirects

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect, wildcard

I am making some redirects with nginx, but for some it automatically matches everything at the end of the URL, which creates redirects to the wrong pages.

I have these two redirects.

```
location /en/blogging {
  return 301 /en/blog;
}

location ~^/en/blogging/(?<suffix>.*)$ {
  return 301 /en;
}
```

The problem is that the first one seems to automatically add a wildcard to the redirect.

**Current outcome:**

> /en/blogging
>
> /en/blogging/test
>
> /en/bloggingtest

All are redirected to

> /en/blog

**Expected outcome:**

> /en/blogging -> /en/blog
>
> /en/blogging/test -> /en
>
> /en/bloggingtest -> No redirect

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `location /en/blogging` which matches any URI that **begins with** `/en/blogging`. You should use `location = /en/blogging` if you want to match the single URI `/en/blogging`.

The statement `location ~^/en/blogging/(?<suffix>.*)$` will match any URI that begins with `/en/blogging/` - but then so does `location /en/blogging/`, but without the added complexity of the regular expression and without capturing the suffix.

For example:

```
location = /en/blogging {
  return 301 /en/blog;
}

location ^~ /en/blogging/ {
  return 301 /en;
}
```

The `^~` modifier may be necessary to change the precedence of the prefix location, particularly if you have other conflicting regular expression locations within the same `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, it is still not working as expected.

/en/blogging/test is now redirected to the correct page (/en) but for some reason /en/bloggingtest is still being redirected to /en/blog. This page should not be redirected at all.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: God bless you. Thank you very much :)